# Pandas to_csv() always give TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge dataset that I need to write to csv into a shared file drive. 
I did this before and worked on the same data. 
The only difference this time is that I changed the deliminator from a comma "," into a semicolon ";", but that shouldn't change anything right?

My data is a pandas dataframe; it has string columns and number columns. Has about 16 million rows, and about 20 columns.

Here's the function I wrote to write my data to csv file in chunks:

```
def write_to_csv_in_chunks(input_data, file_path, chunk_size=1000000):
    total_rows = len(input_data)
    current_row = 0

    while (current_row + chunk_size) < total_rows:
        end_row = current_row + chunk_size
        subset_data = input_data[current_row:end_row-1]
        subset_data.to_csv(os.path.join(file_path, 'row '+ str(current_row) + ' to row '
                                        + str(end_row-1) + '.csv'))
        current_row = end_row
        print('finished writing file up to row ', current_row)

    subset_data = input_data[current_row:]
    subset_data.to_csv(os.path.join(file_path, 'row '+ str(current_row) + ' to last row.csv'),
                       sep=';', index=False)

    return print('all files finished writing')
```

Here's me calling the function:

```
write_to_csv_in_chunks(input_data=data_all, file_path=baseDir)
```

But I keep getting the timeout error when I am in the step of writing the data. (I know this because I have a print statement right before I called the write to csv function):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/distance_analysis serial.py", line 195, in <module>
    write_to_csv_in_chunks(input_data=data_all, file_path=baseDir)
  File "/Users/Documents/helping_fxns.py", line 67, in write_to_csv_in_chunks
    + str(end_row-1) + '.csv'))
  File "/Users/Documents/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1524, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/Users/Documents/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 1656, in save
    f.close()
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

PS: I did research into the topic but couldnt find anything really. Maybe I'm not searching correctly; would appreciate any pointers too.

Comment: Why are you writing one row at a time?

Comment: @StephenRauch oh! im not. im writing 1 million row at a time.

Comment: How long did it take you to write the file? As I have a similar issues with 13 million rows, but it always hangs

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling the delimiter back to ',' to make sure it still works that way

Assuming it does, likely it's a formatting problem - something somewhere along the way has an extra semi-colon in it, is messing up the table structure, and the resulting cascade results in way too much data written to disk or some other such thing

Comment: hmm you are right! comma works still... should've tried that before coming here. thanks very much for the advice!